# How to remove file type abbreviations in front of the file names in vs code explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This appeared after recent update. All files have file type markings in front of file names which is superfluous and distracting. How to remove it?

[image: Problem description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the [new default settings introduced in 1.13.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_changed-setting-defaults) - the file icon theme setting now defaults to "Seti" rather than "None".

You can switch back to "None" with <kbd>F1</kbd> > `Preferences: File Icon Theme` > `None`. Alternatively, just add `"workbench.iconTheme": null` to your `settings.json`.